# Firefox Addon: 'promptService' doesn't work from Mozilla's own sample code

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I've created an extension using the [Mozilla Addon Builder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/tools/builder) that creates a toolbar button. No changes have been made to the code, which is running in the current stable FF 3.

```
var mytestextension = {
  onLoad: function() {
    // initialization code
    this.initialized = true;
    this.strings = document.getElementById("mytestextension-strings");
  },

  onMenuItemCommand: function(e) {
    var promptService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"]
                                  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPromptService);
    promptService.alert(window, this.strings.getString("helloMessageTitle"),
                                this.strings.getString("helloMessage"));
  },

  onToolbarButtonCommand: function(e) {
    // just reuse the function above.  you can change this, obviously!
    mytestextension.onMenuItemCommand(e);
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load", mytestextension.onLoad, false);
```

The toolbar button appears, but on click (which I understand should trigger onToolbarButtonCommand) it does nothing. I'm a little vague about debugging here: it's the first time I've tried a language where the 'hello world' hasn't worked!

Comment: If you turn on the `javascript.options.showInConsole` preference, do you get any errors as a result of clicking the button? Also, what does your XUL look like?

Comment: Thanks Neil. Indeed, I get 'Error: this.strings is undefined
Source File: chrome://myextension/content/overlay.js' once I turn on that preference. Per sdwilsh's answer below it looks like 'this' isn't pointing to anything.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in `onLoad` isn't actually going to be pointing to your object, I believe.  If this is unmodified code, please [file a bug about it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?cc=sdwilsh%40forerunnerdesigns.com&comment=&component=Add-on%20Builder&product=addons.mozilla.org&bug_file_loc=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4831459%2Ffirefox-addon-promptservice-doesnt-work-from-mozillas-own-sample-code) (I've already selected the right component for you), and it should get fixed quickly.

Comment: Thanks. sdwilsh, I've done just that. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=630016.

Comment: I suspect if you replace |this| with |mytestextension|, everything would work just fine.